# What is the first multiple of $(x+5)$ greater than $f(x)$, if $f(x) = (x+5)q(x) + (x+3)$?

Tags: polynomials

This question arose while I was tutoring a grade 11 student on the subjects of polynomial division and the Remainder Theorem, and I could not provide a satisfactory answer to it. Presumably, $f(x)$ is a polynomial. I am aware we can write $f(x)$ in the form
$$
f(x) = d(x)q(x) + r(x)
$$
representing its division by $d(x)$, where $q(x)$ is the quotient of the division and $r(x)$ is the remainder, with deg $r(x) < $ deg $d(x)$. But for
$$
f(x) = (x+5)q(x) + (x+3),
$$ assuming $r(x) = (x+3)$, the strict inequality does not hold. I tried analogously shifting the question to integers, where, for example, we can write 27 upon the division of 6 as
$$
27 = (6)(4) + 3
$$
and we would then have the smallest multiple of 6 greater than 27 is one more than the quotient, so 5. But I am not sure how to extend this to the question posed.

Comment: What is the question?  There are many ways to find $q,r$, but only one where the $r$ has degree smaller than $d$.

Comment: What is the order relation on polynomials?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple"?  What do you mean by "first" and what do you mean by $> f(x)$?  None of those have clear and unambiguous meanings.  It is obvious that $(x+5)(q(x) + 1) = f(x)+2 > f(x)$, but it isn't clear that this is a multiple (it's not a scalar multiple), that it is the "first" and it's worth noting that $(x+5)(q(x) + 2) =f(x) + x+7 \not > f(x)$ .  Your question may or may not be meaningful.

Comment: It might help to know how this question arose--was it part of a homework exercise, something the student thought of, or something else?

Comment: @fleablood I am not sure what I mean. The question was exactly as posed. Glad to see I am not the only one who found it ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{align}
(x+5)(q(x) + 1) 
&= (x+5)q(x) + (x+5) \\
&= (x+5)q(x) + (x+3) + 2 \\
&= f(x) + 2 \\
&> f(x).
\end{align}
So $(x+5)(q(x) + 1)$ is a multiple of $x+5$ that is greater than $f(x)$.

Whether this is the "first" such multiple of $x+5$ is a matter of
interpretation, because for $x=-4$, we have 
$f(x) < (x+5)q(x) < (x+5)(q(x) + 1)$.
I suppose the idea of the exercise was that $q(x)$ is *not* the
quotient in the polynomial division of $f(x)$ by $x+5$;
$$
f(x) = (x+5)(q(x) + 1) - 2,
$$
and therefore the remainder is $-2$,
and the quotient is $q(x) + 1$ which is the other factor in the
"multiple" of $q+5$ that you were asked to find.

Coincidence? I think not.
Admittedly, it does seem like a rather awkward way to
think about polynomial division.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to say the question itself is pretty ambiguous. But thank you for your insight! I did end up figuring out that the intended approach was probably manipulating the expression to obtain the correct quotient for polynomial division of $f(x)$ by $(x+5)$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with your question, but answering on what i have understood from your argument.

I guess your question is not correct. For polynomial division, remainder theorem implies that for f(x) and d(x) **there exists some** q(x) and r(x) such that 
f(x) = d(x)*q(x) + r(x) where deg(r(x)) < deg(d(x)) is satisfied.

For the question you are choosing r(x) and d(x) on your own and trying to violate the theorem which is not correct.

Comment: The question given was exactly as I stated. So are you saying the question is incorrect?

Comment: it is incorrect way of interpreting the theorem i am saying, theorem says with f(x) and (x+5) there is some q(x) and r(x) such that f(x) = (x+5)q(x) + r(x) where deg(r(x)) < deg(x+5) like f(x)=x^2-25 we can have q(x) = x-5 and r(x) =0 satisfies that theorem, you are chosing d(x) and r(x) and finding the f(x) and q(x) which satisfies the theorem which is wrong, you can only chose f(x) and d(x) and find the q(x) and r(x) which satisfies it.

Comment: So in this case, we can rearrange the given expression to be (x+5)(q(x)+1) - 2. And extending from my analogy to integer division, the next multiple of (x+5) greater than f(x) should be (q(x)+1)+1, or q(x)+2?

Comment: first of all there is nothing greater or smaller in polynomials, eg we cant say x^2 > x means x^2 is greater than x, these are inequalities that are true for certain values of x, like this one is true for x>1 or x<-1 and false for 0<=x<=1. so for x>1 or x<-1 x^2 is greater than x, but for 0<=x<=1 x^2 is smaller than x

Comment: got your doubt cleared?

Comment: Please use MathJax/LaTeX when appropriate, for all mathematical text.

Comment: Well saying there is nothing greater or smaller in polynomials I think is not quite correct. We can go ahead and say $x + 10 > -x^2$ $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, for instance. But for the question I posed, I am going to go ahead and say its interpretation was rather ambiguous.

Comment: put x = i in the polynomial, it will be i+10>1, i > -9 which makes no sense again at all

Comment: Yes, that's why I specified real numbers.